# Unit testing Mvc.Compare Attribute incorrectly returns model isValid = true

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

`TryValidateObject` does not seem to work on with the `Compare` model validation attribute when unit testing.

I get `ModelState.IsValid = true`, when I know it is `false` (when unit testing).

I've got this example model:

```
public class CompareTestModel
{
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [System.Web.Mvc.Compare(
         "Password",
          ErrorMessage = "The passwords do not match")]
    public string PasswordCompare { get; set; }
}
```

Using this helper method to validate models when unit testing:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public static class ModelHelper
{
    public static void ValidateModel(
         this Controller controller,
         object viewModel)
    {
        controller.ModelState.Clear();

        var validationContext = new ValidationContext(viewModel, null, null);
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

        Validator.TryValidateObject(
            viewModel,
            validationContext,
            validationResults,
            true);

        foreach (var result in validationResults)
        {
            foreach (var name in result.MemberNames)
            {
                controller.ModelState.AddModelError(name, result.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I run this unit test:

```
    [Test]
    public void CompareAttributeTest()
    {
        // arrange
        var model = new CompareTestModel();
        model.Password = "password";
        model.PasswordCompare = "different password";

        AccountController controller = new AccountController();

        // act
        controller.ValidateModel(model);

        // assert
        Assert.IsFalse(controller.ModelState.IsValid);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CompareAttribute` does not fill in the `ValidationResult`'s class `MemberNames` property (see [source](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/CompareAttribute.cs)). So your `result.MemberNames` will be empty.

Because it is not required to use the `MemberNames` property (the `ValidationResult` even has a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411873.aspx) for this) so you need to change your `ValidateModel` helper to deal with this kind of `ValidationResult`:

```
foreach (var result in validationResults)
{
    if (result.MemberNames.Any())
    {
        foreach (var name in result.MemberNames)
        {
            controller.ModelState.AddModelError(name, result.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
    else
        controller.ModelState.AddModelError("", result.ErrorMessage);
}
```